# Angular adding a hashtag at the end of file path url in $location

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

So, some quick context: I'm building an electron app, so all paths/urls are from file system. Web window starts with a small form, with user/password, and then it redirects to the main app that uses angular. The form is using GET, by the way.

After the redirect, the plan was to get the query parameters with $location, but angular is adding a hashtag and slash at the end of it, and when I try to $location.search() it gives me an empty object.

$location.absUrl() is returning: `file:///C:/blablabla/main.html?user=abc&password=123#/`

So my guess is that hashtag at the end is ruining all my plans. And it's weird, because I'm not using any $route/$location/$state configuration. By the way, the window.location object has the correct path without the hashtag, so I'm guessing this is angular's fault.

I did some search and found some recommendations to use html5Mode, but after trying it seems to not work the way I need, since it needs a baseurl tag with a path.

Any help is going to be appreciated, thanks

Comment: HTML5 Mode has an option to not require a base tag. `$locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: false, rewriteLinks: true})`

Comment: Thanks @RyanHamley! It solved my problem like a charm. It's still strange though, I've had an angular project before in which I didn't need to do this. But I was running in localhost, not in file system. Is it really the file system the problem?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure, because I've never used a file system like that before.  I'm guessing that Angular just maybe doesn't know how to parse the file:// pathway as a URL. I'm not sure it's necessary to do that though. Check out this [Scotch.io article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-desktop-applications-with-angularjs-and-github-electron) on using Angular and Electron.